# Is there any danger in putting a magnet in your ear (next to your brain)

Tags: neuroscience, brain, electrophysiology

I recently bought some wireless earbuds that fit right in my ear, so they're very small.
But the method it uses for charging is magnetic, so it has magnets built into the earbud.

I was wondering if there's any danger in keeping a magnet in your ear for many hours every day? I'm not sure if it would affect things in your skull/brain.

Comment: All speakers, all headphones, and all earbuds contain magnets. That's how the speaker diaphragm is driven. Furthermore you are walking around in the earth's magnetic field all day long. There might be an issue with exposure to a superconducting high field magnet, but you wouldn't be able to fit that in your year.

Comment: @rasen58 As your question comes from a belief popularized by alternative medicines, your question would be a good fit on [skeptics.SE](skeptics.stackexchange.com). You might also want to have a look at the posts [Do magnets have verifiable effects on humans?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/136/do-magnets-have-verifiable-effects-on-humans) and [Do magnetic insoles or bracelets increase muscular strength and flexibility?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10774/do-magnetic-insoles-or-bracelets-increase-muscular-strength-and-flexibility) on skeptics.SE

Comment: @Remi.b I didn't even know that was a belief popularized by alternative medicine. It was just a question that would seem to make sense from a scientific viewpoint since putting powerful things like magnetic fields close to you seems like it could somehow be dangerous. But thanks for the links!

Answer (score -1):

Every pair of earbuds/headphones have magnets in them, as of now there's no solid evidence that proves that they are harmful or harmless to humans. Keep in mind that, what may be harmful to lab rats may not be harmful to humans as we are more resilient to radiation, etc. (In reference to a study done on truly wireless earbuds.)

Comment: You wrote that you a referencing to a certain study, could you please provide a link to that study?